# Should I use useEffect or useRef in order to achieve changing one operator to another in a calculator app built with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I have a component that completes different types of calculation functions. I use the `<textarea>` tag to render user inputs, but I can't achieve the following: when the user types, for example, '45+/', I should change the '+' operator to the '/' operator in order to prevent consecutive input of operators.

I'll provide some snippets of my code

I've done this when the user uses buttons.

```
const handleDrawNumber = (input) => {
    const operators = ["/", "*", "+", "-", "%", "."];

    if (operators.includes(input)) {
      if (operators.includes(result[result.length - 1])) {
        setResult(result.slice(0, result.length - 1) + input);
      } else {
        setResult(result + input);
      }
    } else {
      setResult(result + input);
    }
  };
```

I've tried to resolve this issue when the user uses the keyboard.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("RESULT: " + result);
    console.log("RESULT LENGHT: " + result.length);
    const operators = ["/", "*", "+", "-", "%", "."];
    const handleInput = (input) => {
      if (operators.includes(result[result.length - 1])) {
        const array = result;
        console.log("YES");
        setResult(array.slice(0, array.length - 1) + input);
      } 
    };

    handleInput();
  }, [result]);
////////////////////////////////////////
const handleFromKeyBoard = (input) => {
    setResult(input.target.value);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use either.

You should have an valueInput created by useState and a function() `handleCalculatorInputChange()`.

All your logic should be on this function that manipulates the change. If it was created by keyboard using the onChange callback or the buttons.

First create the code to the keyboard. Then reuse it making the buttons have the same behaviour.